# 3-manifolds with all minimal surfaces closed

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, 3-manifolds, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

**Question.** Let the manifold $(M^3,g)$ be compact without boundary. Suppose that every complete, embedded minimal surface $\Sigma \subset M^3$ is closed. Must $M$ be diffeomorphic to $\mathbf{S}^3$ or $\mathbf{R}P^3$? If not, what if one strengthens the hypothesis to include also all immersed minimal surfaces?

- Similar questions about geodesics are famous, but some of the tools used there—notably geodesic flow—have no immediate analogues in higher dimension.
- Not all three-manifolds satisfy the hypothesis: if $N^2$ is a compact surface that contains a non-closed geodesic, then one can take $M = N \times \mathbf{S}^1$; a concrete example is the three-torus. (Mind you I am not completely sure whether the result even holds in $\mathbf{S}^3$ and $\mathbf{R}P^3$.)

Comment: Regarding your question about immersed surfaces:  Nadirashvili's examples suggest every three manifold admits a complete minimally immersed disk (of course his argument uses the Weierstrass representation so would only hold if if the three manifold had a ball where the metric was flat.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.  Note that all of the spherical space forms either have the property (all complete embedded minimal surfaces closed) or none do.

Does $S^3$ have a disjoint pair of closed, embedded, minimal surfaces?  If so, we might be able to use these to build a minimal lamination via a "spinning construction".

---

On the other hand, the three-sphere (and thus all spherical space forms) contain complete immersed minimal surfaces.  Namely, take a spherical tetrahedron $T$ with four dihedral angles being $\pi/2$ and the remaining two, non-adjacent, dihedral angles being irrational multiplies of $\pi$.  The medial square in $T$, between the two exceptional edges, will be a minimal surface.  Repeatedly reflecting $T$ across its faces, and gluing together the resulting medial squares, gives the desired minimal surface.

There is an easier argument giving immersed minimal (in fact, totally geodesic) surfaces in a closed hyperbolic three-manifolds.  This is because the universal cover is $\mathbb{H}^3$.  So we take an "irrational" geodesic plane, and project it down.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, then the answer is negative: because a round $\mathbf{S}^3$ has positive Ricci curvature, any two closed minimal surfaces in it must intersect. (People usually call this the Frankel theorem.) Still, I am curious about the "spinning construction" you propose. With geodesics in a surface $M^2$, does it work if $M$ is a topological sphere? For example, say $M$ is a rotationally symmetric dumbbell - this would have the two equators disjoint, separated by a stable geodesic in the neck.

Comment: Hmm.  I see how to "spin" in a plane with at least three mushrooms, say in a line.  Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be simple closed curves that enclose (respectively) the left two and the right two mushrooms. So $\alpha$ and $\beta$ meet in two points.  We can now "spin" - namely take one copy of $\alpha$ and $n$ parallel copies of $\beta$ and perform surgeries to get a single curve...